# Не выводится текущая дата в календаре html

Tags: javascript, html, дата, календарь

У меня есть поле с календарём:`<input type="date" name="date1" id="davaToday" value="" />`

Я прописал в js такую строку: `document.getElementById('davaToday').valueAsDate = new Date();` чтобы  в календаре  указывалась текущая дата. 
Но у меня указывается не текущая, а вчерашняя т.е. вместо 02.10.2016 в календаре 01.10.2016.

Comment: Кстати, могут быть проблемы у пользователей, у которых нет батарейки в компьютере, связи с тем, что их пояс сбит, твой календарь покажет им нереальные циферки =). Советую использовать сервер, для передачи правильной зоны и времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно вычислить разницу в часовых поясах из настроек времени на компьютере, а дальше уже прибавить разницу к текущей даже получаемой с помощью `new Date();`

```js
var date = new Date(); // Получаем текущую дату
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = -date.getTimezoneOffset()/60; // Получаем разницу в часовых поясах

date.setHours(date.getHours() + currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours); // Прибавляем к текущей дате разницу и сохраняем в переменной date
document.getElementById('davaToday').valueAsDate = date; // Присваиваем значение даты в input
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date1" id="davaToday" value="" />
```